# Program not outputting desired output in specific scenario: stacks and parsing

Tags: c++, stack

So the goal of this program is to read a text file of code and make sure there is an even balance of `[], (), {}`, using a stack.

The first .txt file I have to read is as follows:

```
{}   }
```

once read, the program should return a pair matching `{  }` and an unbalance symbol `}` (which it does successfully!)

The second.txt file I have to read is as follows:

```
{}
```

and it should return a balance and even pair matching `{ }` (which it does successfully!)

The third text file should read as follows:

```
{  {}
```

and it should return a matching pair `{  }` (which it does) AND an unbalance symbol `{`, **(Which it doesn't)**. It only returns pair matching `{ }` (which is true), but it should also print out that there is an unbalance `{`. Anyone know why it won't work in this specific scenario?

Comment: If you guys need further clarification on anything PLEASEEEE let me know. This is the only problem I have with my program and I can't figure out why it does this.

Comment: put the language as a tag, not on title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the code you have written you need to check if the file has reached eof but stack is not empty . If stack is not empty, you have to print the content of the stack as unbalanced.

After the while loop,

```
  while(!STACK.empty()){
          char b = STACK.top();
          if(b == '(' || b == '{' || b== '['){
              cout << b << "is unbalanced" << endl;
             sameSymbol = false;
          }

          STACK.pop()
    }
```

To resolve your line number query:

```
bool sameSymbol = true;
stack <char> STACK;
char a, b;

while (true)
    {
        if(!textfile.get(a)) {
            while(!STACK.empty()){
                char b = STACK.top();
                if(b == '(' || b == '{' || b== '['){
                    cout << b << "is unbalanced" << endl;
                   sameSymbol = false;
                }

               STACK.pop()
            }
            break;
        }


        // if a is a (, {, or [, push onto the stack
        if (a == '(' || a == '{' || a == '[')
        {
            STACK.push(a);
        }
        // if a is a ), }, or ]
        else if (a == ')' || a == '}' || a == ']')
        {
            //if the stack is empty, return false
            if (STACK.empty())
            {
                cout << "unbalanced symbol " << a << " at line " << endl;
                sameSymbol = false;             
                break;
            }
            b = STACK.top();
            STACK.pop();
            if (TestIfMatching(a, b))
            {
                cout << "pair matching " << b << " and " << a << endl;
                sameSymbol = true;
            }
            // if a and b are not matching parenthesis return false
            if (!TestIfMatching(a, b))
            {
                cout << "unbalanced " << a << " symbol at line " << endl;
                sameSymbol = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I only need to find the first unbalance. Once I find one unbalanced symbol I can break out of the loop. Also I already have an  `if (!STACK.empty())
  sameSymbol= false;` after my while loop. and after that at the end if sameSymbol is true print out "No errors" or if it is false I print out "Error was found"

Comment: See in 3rd case {{} , it goes to first {, put it in stack. Then next { , put it in stack as well. And then it goes to } it checks for stack.empty which is false,so, it finds stack.top() which is { and it matches correctly so it gives you balanced pair. But now the stack has still { despite the file has reached eof. To handle this case, you will have to add the code that I have provided.

Comment: can you show that part of code as well? And the output that you get in third case?

Comment: Great explanation - I see what you mean now. Sure I can provide it one second

Comment: Awesome! Thank you :)

Comment: when I do this it messes up the other parts of my project - because this is just one section it. I also check for single quotes, double quotes, comments, and block comments. They don't have this issue of one being left over

Comment: if (!STACK.empty())
        sameSymbol= false;  
You don't need this. Because STACK will be empty before here.
How does it messes up?

Comment: See the updated code. It deals with the braces only. This shud work properly now.

Comment: Ok it is because I have in my code a line tracker in the loop which keeps track of every line of code it goes through and when it finds an error it also prints the line number so it does cout << b << " is unbalanced at line " << lineNumber;. So I think it has to be in the loop. Otherwise it doesn't give the line number that the unbalance is found at

Comment: It works but I'm trying to put it somewhere in the loop because if it is outside the loop it doesn't give the line number that the error was found at

Comment: I have updated the code to get it inside the loop. Accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: No if I do that it messes up the quotation and comment ones

Comment: What do you actually mean by line number? Is it your line number of the code?

Comment: whenever I read in one line from the text file I increase my variable linetracker++;. Then when I have to print unbalance on line ___ i can do cout << "unbalance " << b << " on line " << linetracker;

Comment: So best is that you store that line number in your stack itself. Make a Stack<pair<char,int> > and store the character and line number. Now wherever you are displaying stack.top().first as character, stack.top().second will be corresponding line number.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help I will do that

Comment: No problem! :) Happy to help!